# How to restrict web site using both HTTP Basic Authentication and IP address with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip-address, basic-authentication

I am using .htaccess to restrict access to a web service:

```
<LimitExcept OPTIONS>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

Is there a way to require a specific IP address, so that the client must provide the correct name/password AND be at one of several allowed IP addresses?

Comment: You could use `Require ip IP` but the Apache docs says: `When using <Limit> or <LimitExcept> directives with the Require directive, note that the first Require to succeed authorizes the request, regardless of the presence of other Require directives.` Do you just want to limit `OPTIONS` or just completely block access?

Comment: I would like to block all access from an unauthorized IP, including OPTIONS. However, the "first Require succeeds" rule doesn't achieve what I need, since I need both options to pass. I may have to use server-side code to whitelist the IP after the Basic Authentication succeeds.

Comment: Why don't you use `<RequireAll>` instead of `<LimitExcept>`? Is there a specific need for not limiting `OPTIONS`?

Comment: Yes, I have to enable CORS.